# Where can I have photos printed in bulk at wholesale prices?

Tags: printing, service-recommendation, selling, photolabs

I would like to sell prints of my photos, does anyone have know of any suppliers that print photos off in bulk? Ideally based in the UK but I would also consider printers abroad.

I don't want to use sites like PhotoBox, Snapfish because the margins will be lower.

Comment: You might want to state print size, finish and quantity.

Comment: If you were in the US, I'd recommend http://bigphotohelp.com/. The prices are pretty good, turnaround is great, and quality is acceptable to great so far (I've had no complaints with what I've received in the past.) Their web site looks pretty cheap, but thats kind of what you want if your looking for low cost. You might try looking for something similar in the UK.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't print very often; I use boots (photobox) when I do, but I would love to find out about a bulk printer in the UK.  Hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ProAm Imaging](http://www.proamimaging.com/), based in Bradford. I haven't used them personally but have heard good things, and they have apparently won awards. 52p each for 8x10" prints. Sell them for £5 each and you're laughing!

Comment: Just had some prints sent to me and the packaging and quality is great, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [DS Colour Labs](http://www.dscolourlabs.co.uk).  50p for a 10x8 and really good quality

Answer (score 0):

I have heard nothing but good things about DS Colour Labs in Manchester, Loxley Colour Labs in Glasgow and Trumps in Edinburgh.